# Magnolia - creating new area

Tags: templating, magnolia

I read magnolia documentation, but I'm still not sure how to create new area for existing page. What I want to do is Banner area (with image and some text) above `<div id="wrapper-2">`. I'm using Magnolia CE 4.5.9.

What I should do is probably:

1) add new area to: **[templating-kit tab]**`/templates/prototype/areas`

2) add a line like `[@cms.area name="banner" content=content/]` to `/templating-kit/pages/main` **[templating-kit/templates] tab**

3) something in **[configuration] tab** (?)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step by step guide is at http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/templates/introduction.html#Areas

HTH,
Jan